# ajax in laravel not showing. but in console , i can see the get url

Tags: ajax, laravel, controller, dropdown, html-select

I am making 2 dropdown which is the second one is dependent from first one. And here is my view code:

```
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="form-label">General</label>
                    <select class="form-control formselect required" 
                                     placeholder="Select Category" id="sub_category_name">
                                         <option value="0" disabled selected>Select
                                         Main Category*</option>
                                      @foreach($data as $categories)
                                       <option  value="{{ $categories->id }}">
                                       {{ ucfirst($categories->catname) }}</option>
                                        @endforeach
                    </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="form-label">Sub</label>
                                            <select class="form-control formselect required" 
                                      placeholder="Select Sub Category" id="sub_category">
                                          </select>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
```

Then here is my code in controller :
public function index(Request $request)
{

```
    $data = DB::table('cats')->get();
    return view('admin.genc.gencEntry')->with('data', $data);
    }
  

    public function subcat($id){
        echo json_encode(DB::table('subcats')->where('catid', $id)->get());
    }
```

And ajax is here:

```
<script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#sub_category_name').on('change', function () {
            let id = $(this).val();
            $('#sub_category').empty();
            $('#sub_category').append(`<option value="0" disabled selected>Processing...</option>`);
            $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: 'subcat/' + id,
            success: function (response) {
            var response = JSON.parse(response);
            console.log(response);   
            $('#sub_category').empty();
            $('#sub_category').append(`<option value="0" disabled selected>Select Sub Category*</option>`);
            response.forEach(element => {
                $('#sub_category').append(`<option value="${element['id']}">${element['subcatname']}</option>`);
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But when i select a option from first dropdown, second one is not showing anything.
But i can see  **XHR finished loading: GET "http://www.example.com:8000/genc/subcat/7"** in my console.

Can someone tell me where is the error causing the empty dropdown?

Answer (score 0):

It's look like issue with your loop syntax, use it like
$.each(response, function(key,element) {
$('#sub_category').append(`<option value="${element['id']}">${element['subcatname']}</option>`);
});